# how to wait in asynctask class until its task completed

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am new to Asynctask coding, and am having some issues.

In my code I have defined a subclass in an `onClick` listener, and in that class I have created an Asynctask which is using HTTP connections, and has some XML parsing code. The problem is, when I click on my button it is not waiting for the asynch task to complete, and instead it gives an error saying "Out of Bound in main class". There is no opportunity to process my PostExecute because XML parsing in the Async task throws an exception like: "NetworkOnMainThread".

I could really use some help uncovering my bug, here is my code:

```
public class GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser {

    public static ArrayList<GetDirectoryInfoTableContent> tableContent;
    private GetDirectoryInfoTableContent table;
    private Thread alertThread;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Context context;
    InputStream is;

    public GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser(SettingsPage settings) {
        this.context = settings;
    }

    public void getDataFromUrl(String webSite) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {

        if (webSite != null) {
            alert(context);
            GetDirectoryInfoAsyncTask gDirectoryInfoAsyncTask = new GetDirectoryInfoAsyncTask();
            gDirectoryInfoAsyncTask.execute(webSite);
        } else {

        }
    }

    private class GetDirectoryInfoAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                    "http://mobile.primemrm.com/mobile.asmx/GetDirectoryInfo");
            ProtocolVersion protocolVersion = post.getProtocolVersion();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sUrl", params[0]));

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            XmlPullParserFactory factory;
            try {
                factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
                // InputStream is = getURlResponse(params[0]);

                if (is == null) {
                    Log.e("GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser", "InputStream is Null");
                    return null;
                }

                else if (is != null) {
                    Log.e("GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser",
                            "InputStream is Not Null");
                    parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(is));
                }

                int eventType = parser.getEventType();
                String name;

                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                        tableContent = new ArrayList<GetDirectoryInfoTableContent>();
                    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        name = parser.getName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Table")) {
                            table = new GetDirectoryInfoTableContent();
                            /*
                             * for(int i = 0; i< parser.getAttributeCount();
                             * i++){
                             * if(parser.getAttributeName(i).equalsIgnoreCase
                             * ("id")){
                             * table.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(i)); }else
                             * if(parser.getAttributeName(i).equalsIgnoreCase(
                             * "rowOrder"));
                             * table.setRowOrder(parser.getAttributeValue(i)); }
                             */
                        } else if (name
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("EnablePublicMemberDirectory")) {
                            table.setEnablePublicMemberDirectory(parser
                                    .nextText());
                            Log.e("GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser",
                                    "EnablePublicMemberDirectory : "
                                            + table.getEnablePublicMemberDirectory());
                        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Response")) {
                            table.setEnablePublicMemberDirectory(parser
                                    .nextText());

                        }
                    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                        name = parser.getName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Table")) {
                            tableContent.add(table);
                            table = null;
                        }
                    }

                    eventType = parser.next();
                }

            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public void alert(final Context context) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...");
        alertThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        alertThread.start();
    }
}
```

---

Thanks In advance.

Edited:

verify.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String logingString = login.getText().toString();
            String passwordString = password.getText().toString();
             websiteString = websiteUrl.getText().toString();
            if (websiteString.equals(pref.getString(WEBSITE, null))
                    && logingString.equals(pref.getString(PREF_USERNAME,
                            null))
                    && passwordString.equals(pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD,
                            null))) {
                //return;
            }
            if (saveCredientials(logingString, passwordString,
                    websiteString)) {
                /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Saved User Name & Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();*/

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User Name (or) Password is empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            sVersion = version.getText().toString();
            sWesiteUrl = websiteUrl.getText().toString();
            sLogin = login.getText().toString();
            sPassword = password.getText().toString();
            if (sWesiteUrl == null || sWesiteUrl == ""
                    || sWesiteUrl.length() == 0) {
                Log.e("SettingsPage", "Jhansi check 1 sWebsite is null");
                websiteNullAlertDialog();
                //return;
            } else if (sWesiteUrl != null) {
                try {
                    getDirectoyrInforParser.getDataFromUrl(sWesiteUrl);
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser.tableContent != null) {

                    if (GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser.tableContent.get(0)
                            .getEnablePublicMemberDirectory()
                            .equals("true")) {
                        Log.e("SettingsPage",
                                "Jhansi check 2 sWebsite is Public");
                        isLoginSucess = true;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsPage.this,
                                HomePage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("wesiteLogoUrl", sWesiteUrl);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else if (GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser.tableContent
                            .get(0).getEnablePublicMemberDirectory()
                            .equals("false")) {
                        Log.e("SettingsPage",
                                "Jhansi check 3 sWebsite is Private");
                        // ifMember();
                        if (sLogin == null || sLogin.equals("")
                                || sLogin.length() == 0
                                || sPassword == null
                                || sPassword.equals("")
                                || sPassword.length() == 0) {
                            Log.e("SettingsPage",
                                    "Jhansi check 4 loging is null");
                            ifMember();
                            // m.sivajhansi
                            return;
                            // alertDialog();

                        }

                        try {
                            parser.getDataFromUrl(sWesiteUrl, sLogin,
                                    sPassword);

                        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        if (LoginXMLParser.tableContent != null
                                && LoginXMLParser.tableContent.size() > 0 && sLogin.equals(LoginXMLParser.tableContent
                                        .get(0).getContact_email())
                                        && sPassword
                                                .equals(LoginXMLParser.tableContent
                                                        .get(0)
                                                        .getContact_password())) {
                            Log.e("SettingsPage", "data is  : "
                                    + LoginXMLParser.tableContent);
                            /*if (isLoginCorrect && sLogin.equals(LoginXMLParser.tableContent
                                    .get(0).getContact_email())
                                    && sPassword
                                            .equals(LoginXMLParser.tableContent
                                                    .get(0)
                                                    .getContact_password())) {*/
                            isLoginSucess = true;
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsPage.this,
                                        "Login Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();

                                // isLoginSucess = true;

                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        SettingsPage.this, HomePage.class);
                                intent.putExtra("wesiteLogoUrl", sWesiteUrl);
                                startActivity(intent);
                        //  }
                        /*
                             * else { Log.e("SettingsPage",
                             * "Jhansi check 5 "); alertDialog(); }
                             */

                        }else {
                          Log.e("SettingsPage", "DATA CHECK");
                        // m.sivajhansi
                            alertDialog();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.e("SettingsPage", "Jhansi check 7");
                        websiteNullAlertDialog();

                    }
                } else if (GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser.tableContent == null){
                    Log.e("SettingsPage", "Jhansi check 8");
                    websiteNullAlertDialog();

                }

            }
        }

    });
```

The Class which is called onclick is:

public class GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser {

```
public static ArrayList<GetDirectoryInfoTableContent> tableContent;
private GetDirectoryInfoTableContent table;

public void getDataFromUrl(String webSite)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
    InputStream is = getURlResponse(webSite);

    if (is == null) {
        Log.e("GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser", "InputStream is Null");
        return ;
    }

    else if (is != null) {
        Log.e("GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser", "InputStream is Not Null");
        parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(is));
    }

    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    String name;

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            tableContent = new ArrayList<GetDirectoryInfoTableContent>();
        }else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
            name = parser.getName();
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Table")){
                table = new GetDirectoryInfoTableContent();
                /*for(int i = 0; i< parser.getAttributeCount(); i++){
                    if(parser.getAttributeName(i).equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                        table.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(i));
                    }else if(parser.getAttributeName(i).equalsIgnoreCase("rowOrder"));
                        table.setRowOrder(parser.getAttributeValue(i));
                }*/
            }else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("EnablePublicMemberDirectory")){
                table.setEnablePublicMemberDirectory(parser.nextText());
                Log.e("GetDirectoryInfoXMLParser", "EnablePublicMemberDirectory : "+table.getEnablePublicMemberDirectory());
            } else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Response")){
                table.setEnablePublicMemberDirectory(parser.nextText());

            }
        }else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
            name = parser.getName();
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Table")){
                tableContent.add(table);
                table = null;
            }
        }

        eventType = parser.next();
    }


}

public InputStream getURlResponse(String webSite) {
    InputStream is = null;

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "http://mobile.primemrm.com/mobile.asmx/GetDirectoryInfo");
    ProtocolVersion protocolVersion = post.getProtocolVersion();
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs
            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("sUrl", webSite));

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return is;

}
```

}

Now this is my code working perfectly upto2.3.3,beacause of strictMode i got "NetworkOnMainThread"..so please Help from this Hell by giving me some Outline to handle this..Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Essentially when extending an AsyncTask,

you need to override the onPreExecute () - you can use this to start showing your dialogbox.

doInBackground()- you can do your blocking/network operations here

onPostExecute - this will fire once all operations in doInBackground is finished. so you can dismiss the dialogbox and use the data that you got from doInBackground.

Comment: Can you change your existing code to the manner i've described and post your code?

Comment: yes i changed.but its not working as need..can you tell me is there any way to handle network calls on UI thread,other than Asynctask method..i struggling here from so many days...